# Sequent Calculus in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic, sequent-calculus

I'm really new to programming in Prolog. I have to program the rules of Sequent Calculus in Prolog, which I think, I did right. The code should succeed if the formula is valid and fail if it's not. Here is my code:

```
:- op(1150, xfy, and).
:- op(1150, xfy, or).
:- op(1150, xfy, implies).
:- op(1150, xfy, iff).
:- op(1150, fx,  neg).

sc(A,B) :-
    \+ intersection(A,B,[]), !.

sc([neg(F),L1], B) :-
    sc(L1,[F|B]), !.

sc(A, [neg(F),IL]) :-
    sc([F|A],L), !.

sc(A, [F1 or F2 | L]) :-
    sc(A,B), union([F1,F2],LB), !.

sc([F1 or F2 | L], B) :-
    sc([F1|L],B), sc([F2,L,B]), !.

sc(A,B) :-
    \+ atom(A), permutation(A,A1), sc(A1,B), !.

sc(A,B) :-
    \+ atom(B), permutation(B,B1), sc(A,B1), !.
```

And this returns true if the formula is valid.

But if I run the code with an invalid formula, it never ends, and I really don't know how I can fix it.

The query `-? sc([ ],[ (neg ((neg p)or neg (neg p)))]).` should fail because that formula is invalid.

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image. Post it as text so that we can work with it. Most users will not attempt to answer a question without code as text.

Comment: Sorry, I will post it as text in future moments.

Comment: Does that mean you're going to edit this question?

Comment: Please show what query you ran and what result you expected.

Comment: @lurker The entry   "-? sc([ ],[ (neg ((neg p)or neg (neg p)))])." should return false, because that formula is not valid.

Comment: Please edit your question and put the actual text of your code there. Select it all and click the `{}` button to format it properly. Do you know that `[ (neg ((neg p)or neg (neg p)))]` is a list of one element?

Comment: copy the code as text please. also please copy several successful queries, showing their outputs. also copy actual failing query from your REPL. alternatively, please provide a link to a live code entry somewhere, like https://tio.run, https://swish.swi-prolog.org, or something.

Answer (score 4):

There is an error in the disjunction rule. Further the 
permutation rule is a structural rule:

```
G, A, B, D |- C
---------------
G, B, A, D |- C
```

And you should code it, so that it doesn't loop. But now this can exactly happen. There is a simple trick, maybe you wanted to implement it, only swap in non-atoms to the fronts.

Here is a cleaned up version:

```
:- use_module(library(basic/lists)).

sc([neg(A)|L],R) :- !, sc(L,[A|R]).
sc(L,[neg(A)|R]) :- !, sc([A|L],R).
sc(L,[or(A,B)|R]) :- !, sc(L,[A,B|R]).
sc([or(A,B)|L],R) :- !, sc([A|L],R), sc([B|L],R).
sc([A|L],R) :- atom(A), select(B,L,H), compound(B), !, sc([B,A|H],R).
sc(L,[A|R]) :- atom(A), select(B,R,H), compound(B), !, sc(L,[B,A|H]).
sc(L,R) :- member(A,L), member(A,R), !.
```

And here are some runs:

```
Jekejeke Prolog 3, Runtime Library 1.3.5
(c) 1985-2019, XLOG Technologies GmbH, Switzerland

?- sc([],[neg(or(neg(p),neg(neg(p))))]).
No
?- sc([],[or(neg(p),neg(neg(p)))]).
Yes
```

Remarks: I have moved the identity rule to the end, so it will only hit atoms. I have placed cuts, which is justified by some [inversion lemmas](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15317-f09/lectures/11-inversion.pdf) for classical logic. Might not work for other logics or when non-ground problems are posed.

Comment: Oh thanks. I just made another kind of corrections in my code using permutation in a different way and it works.

Comment: I've just posted my new code down. Is it always necessary to put the identity rule to the end? @j4n burn53

Comment: No, I guess you can also allow a rule G, A |- A, D and not only G, P |- P, D. At least in classical logic I guess you can show that the former is also derivable.

Comment: I just saw, your identity rule was correct. Provided the intersection/3 predicate is steadfast enough to be able to be called like this. So I edited my post, there was no error in the identity rule.

Answer (score 2):

```
:- use_module(library/basic/lists)).

sc(I,D) :- \+(intersection(I,D,[])),!.
sc([(neg F)|I],D) :- sc2(I,[F|D]),!.
sc(I,[(neg F)|D]) :- sc2([F|I],D),!.
sc(I,[(F1 or F2)|D]) :- union([F1,F2],D,D1),sc2(I,D1),!.
sc([(F1 or F2)|I],D) :- sc2([F1|I],D),sc2([F2|I],D),!.
sc2(I,D):-permutation(I,I1),permutation(D,D1),sc(I1,D1).
```

Comment: Did you try sc([],[neg(or(neg(p),neg(neg(p))))]) again ?